# How to update the document back after expiration?

Tags: couchbase

Initially a document is with State-A. It is updated with State-B with expiration. After expiration, will the document automatically updated with State-A. If not, what is the solution to make it happen?

Answer (score 1):

after you update the document, the previous data lost. so you cannot just revert to previous state. what you can, is to implement versions manually.

for example your application has document with key `foo`, then you can do the following behind scenes:

setting

```
my_set("foo", "bar")
```

translates to

```
v = incr("foo:ver")
set("foo:" + v, "bar")
```

and getting

```
my_get("foo")
```

translates to

```
v = get("foo:ver")
loop do
  doc = get("foo:" + v)
  v -= 1
  break if v < 0 || doc.present?
end
```

I this pseudo code I've shown the basic idea, of course it maybe be optimized, like updating counter after successful get.

And in this setting `my_set()` can accept expiration time, and all previous values will be safely stored.